# bulk insert task issue

Tags: ssis, etl

I am facing a issue with Bulk Insert Task, which tries to pull data from .DAT file to SQL server table. The error which I am getting is as follows :

Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Localpath" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3 (Could not find the path)

It would be helpful, if you could help me out.

Comment: The error is very clear: You passed the wrong file path. Did you check whether the file exists? How did you pass the file path? As a relative or absolute value?

Comment: The path was correct. I had checked. I used expression for connectionstring

Comment: What connection string?? The bulk insert path points to a file, not a database. What is the exact path you used? Does the path exist *on the server where the task runs?*

Comment: I had pointed to a file. I had used my local path. this is an existing package which is working fine in the Production server. I took the package from there for enhancement. And pointed to my local path in the Bulk Insert Task. I also changed my local path as "\\<<MACHINE IP>>\C$\<<PATH>>", then also I am facing the same issue

Comment: As I already said, it doesn't matter that it works on the server. *What is the path you used*? To convince yourself that SSIS didn't suddenly decide to stop working, just create a new package, add a single Bulk Insert Task and point it to a file on your machine. Debug the package and see what it does

Comment: I did. Same issue I am facing. I had set the path as "L:/Samples/Bulkupload.dat"

Comment: You typed `/ ` instead of `\ ` ? If that's not a typo, the path is invalid. It should be `L:\Samples\Bulkupload.dat` . Even if you fix it, *do* you have an L: drive on *your* machine? Is it a real drive or a network drive? If it's a mapped drive on the server, make sure you also create a mapped drive on your machine and assign it the letter `L`

Comment: I believe it is a mapped drive shared to my machine and displayed as L drive

Comment: Mapped drives aren't shared. *You* create mapped drives that *point* to a network share. If you don't create them, they don't exist, unless a domain administrator creates them with a Group Policy. Moreover, if you don't have permissions to read the file, it won't appear in the drive.

Answer (score 2):

A BULK INSERT task in SSIS works in the context of the SQL Server which it is being executed from.  So if you have a package executing on Server A and it executes a Bulk Insert task on Server B, it will look for the file on Server B, unless you are using a UNC path.

Using a UNC path could introduce other problems however, such as the need for kerberos in order to authenticate to the SSIS Server.  This could be your situation, or you could have simply passed the wrong path to the task.  In either case, it is ridiculously simpler to configure and troubleshoot a data flow task.  I would suggest trying that as a replacement.

Comment: The path was correct. I had checked. This is an existing package. It is currently working fine in Production server. I took the package from Production server for modification, which I came through the Bulk Insert Task for first time and when failed at the said task. In my machine, I had pointed to my local path for flat file inside the source for Bulk Insert Task. What UNC path ? What UNC path do u suggest which would work fine in local machine ?

Comment: I tried my local path as "\\<<MACHINE IP>>\C$\<<Path>>". then also I face the same issue, mentioning Access Denied too

Comment: @SreejeshKumar what is the exact path you used? It doesn't matter that it works in production when you run it on a different machine. Unless the task already uses a UNC path, it has a local absolute path. The same file should exist on your development machine at the same path

Comment: @SreejeshKumar The UNC path you tried is *equivalent* to `C:\...`. If the file doesn't exist, you won't find it just because you used UNC. `C$` also requires admin access and is rarely used. Normal use is to create a file share *but that isn't your issue*.

Comment: I had set the path as "L:/Samples/Bulkupload.dat". I tried to create a shared path. It seems that there is restriction in the machine I am using, as I am working in a Virtual Machine which is the client server

Comment: Network drives aren't shares. You create a network drive to point to a share for easier access. Typically, this isn't restricted because it's a per-user setting